# Ninject ActivationStrategy does not get called when activation result is null

Tags: c#, ninject

I might have some misunderstanding with the behavior of `ActivationStrategy`. Here is the code that explains it:

```
void Main()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Settings.AllowNullInjection = true;
    kernel.Components.Add<IActivationStrategy, NinjectLoggingStrategy>();
    kernel.Bind<C>().ToProvider(new CallbackProvider<C>(ctx =>
    {
//              return null;
        return new C();
    }));

    kernel.Get<A>();
}

public class A {public A(B b){}}
public class B {public B(C c){}}
public class C {}

public class NinjectLoggingStrategy : ActivationStrategy
{
    private static string RequestPath(IRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null) return "";
        var parentRequest = request.ParentRequest;
        return RequestPath(parentRequest) + " => " + request.Service.Name;
    }

    public override void Activate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference)
    {
        var parentRequest = context.Request.ParentRequest;
        var parentReference = parentRequest == null ? "" : parentRequest.Service.FullName;

        Console.WriteLine("Activating: " + reference.Instance.GetType().FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Activation Path: " + RequestPath(context.Request));
        base.Activate(context, reference);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Activating: UserQuery+C
Activation Path:  => A => B => C
Activating: UserQuery+B
Activation Path:  => A => B
Activating: UserQuery+A
Activation Path:  => A
```

Above is the entire code written in Linqpad, note the line in CallBackProvider that returns null that is commented out at the moment.

> //              return null;

If I un-comment this line, the result will be:

```
Activating: UserQuery+B
Activation Path:  => A => B
Activating: UserQuery+A
Activation Path:  => A
```

My understanding is that regardless of the activation result, ActivationStrategy should always be called.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace _as text_ in your question, not as screen capture.

Comment: @Steven the stack trace is actually irrelevant here. I should remove it. The question is about the behavior of ninject activation strategy.

Comment: @Steven I removed it. The deleted part explains why I was looking into Ninject ActivationStrategy.